# Hide the "login process" for an iOS app

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am creating an iOS app that will present a news flow from an Intranet site. I have created a `UIWebView` that displays a mobile page of the Intranet site, and users must login first time they use the app (then credentials are remembered and automatically filled in next time).

When the application is started, then first it loads a page where users must enter login credentials and click button "login" and then they are redirected to a mobile page. Next time it performs the login procedure automatically as the credentials are remembered, however it takes 1-2 seconds to process the login, and I would like to hide the login page by adding some sort of delay.

**Important:**

I have read different topics, where people refer to `Apple` sites that say `try to avoid delaying your app`. I don't want to delay the app, I just want to hide the login procedure from users, as it is there anyway, and show a company logo instead.

So there will be 2 scenarios.

**First time login:**

Display logo for 2 sec (delay) > login page > News flow

**Following logins:**

Display logo for 2 sec (hide the login procedure) > News flow

What is the best practice to achieve that goal?

Thank you in advance.

Igor

Comment: There is not best practice since it is meanly depended on your knowledge of the iOS SDK. So any answer given will be completely depended on users opinion. Also you question looks like a code request which is frowned up and might get you downvoted. You might just want to try and build the app and if you are stuck with some code come back and post the code so that we can help you solve your issue. Also with the delay the documentation does not mean that you can not show a logo.

Comment: Thanks for a reply. I have created the app and it works on the devices as expected, so far tested only on my own devices, but I would like to increase the user experience and hide the login procedure from users, if they already filled in credentials once. I have just started with iOS developing, and don't know so many tricks yet, therefore I posted my question here.

Comment: You need to use NSUserDefaults to persist the user login data in the application. Then on subsequent launches of the app, check whether the value exists in NSUserDefaults or not before proceeding.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I don't have problems with automatic login procedure, I just want to hide that part from users, as it might confuse them.
Application starts with the login screen, and then proceeds to news flow page, and everything works fine, I just want to hide the login phase, and display something else before News are loaded in UIWebView.

Answer (score 0):

When your application starts you will want to check to see if you have stored credentials and if so call a method that does something similar to:

```
 //display your logo preferably with an activity indicator

dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
// authenticate 

dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //if success load news flow 
    //else show login page
    // remove logo
});
});
```